# echo a tax term in loop

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I need to echo a term of a CPT in this loop after the

for each item in the list. Any direction or help is appreciated. Original code is from Stackoverflow.com because it worked.

```
 <?php
$da_place = get_field('smart_place'); //acf field

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'to_do_items',
        'tax_query' => array(
            relation => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'days',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'tuesday',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'places',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $da_place,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );    
?> Tuesday <?

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '';
        echo  '</li>' ;
echo $specialTermHere;
    }echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'Nothing Today';
    // no posts found
} 

//end of Tues
?>
```

Comment: Use [wp_get_object_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) to get all terms for your current post in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the term link of the of each post. I will explain how you should get the answer for this.

First you will need get the term object of current post. Support your taxonomy name is 'your_taxonomy';

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'your_taxonomy' );
```

Because `$term` here is an array, in most case you will need the first one:

```
$term = $terms[0];
```

Then you can get the link to your term by using `get_term_link` function. You can use `printf` to make code easier to read:

```
printf(
    '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%2$s</a>',
    esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ),
    esc_html( $term->name )
);
```

Because you will you this code in a loop, it makes sense to wrap all the logic in a function with two parameters (post ID and taxonomy name).